# How to replace all elements of Python NumPy Array that are greater than a several values?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math

I know that I can replace all elements of Python NumPy Array that are greater than some value:

```
np.putmask(A, A>0.5, 5)
```

Where `A>0.5` is the threshold and 5 the new replacement. However, how can I do it for more conditions? for example for:

```
if x.all <0:
    return 00.1
elif x.all >0:
    return 1
```

Where x is an array. I tried to:

```
np.putmask(x, x<0, 00.1)
```

and

```
np.putmask(x, x>0, 1)
```

However, I would like to do it in a single line. Any idea of how to do this type of replacements in just a single line with putmask or any other method?

Comment: Write your own.

Comment: Why this arbitrary restriction? It can be done, but it'd be silly.

Comment: @tumbleweed How does partial differentiation require doing the two replacements in a single line?

Comment: can you provide an example? @Goyo

Comment: *stepwise function* - maybe you are after something like this: `(x > 0) * 0.9 + 0.1` (presumably, `x` is a numpy array)

Comment: If you want to implement a stepwise function, you can do `f(x) if x > 0 else g(x)`. This might be a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you describe exactly what you want to do? Showing us the relevant code of what you've done so far might help.

Comment: @tumbleweed sorry, I misread your code. `clip` is not useful here.

Comment: Your title asks about setting setting some values to something. Part of your question question also asks about that. But then you ask how to do multiple reassignments in one line. So I ask you why it's necessary to be done in one line and you say you're trying to implement a stepwise function. Then, the conditional block in your code has to do about returning a value from a function, not assigning a value. I see 3 different questions here, what is the **one** thing you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for dual np.where i.e

```
A = np.array([0,1,2,3,1,-5,-6,-7])

k = np.where(A>0,1,np.where(A<0,0.01,A))
```

Or you can use `np.select` for multiple conditions .

```
k = np.select([A>0,A<0],[1,.01],A)
```

Ouptut :

```
[ 0.    1.    1.    1.    1.    0.01  0.01  0.01]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can create masks (logical arrays) of each condition, and then apply all masks.

```
# Create masks
mask1 = (x < 0)
mask2 = (x > 0)
# Apply masks
x[mask1] = 0.1
x[mask2] = 1
```

If you really need it on a single line:

```
mask1 = (x < 0); mask2 = (x > 0); x[mask1] = 0.1; x[mask2] = 1
```

You may also use the `putmask` function as in your example code:

```
mask1 = (x < 0); mask2 = (x > 0); np.putmask(x, mask1, 00.1); np.putmask(x, mask2, 1)
```

Comment: Why exactly does this solution not work for you? If you want it "in a single line" just write all 4 expressions separated by `;`s.

Comment: `np.putmask(x, x<0, 00.1; x, x>0, 1)` like this?

Comment: No, like this: `mask1 = (x < 0); mask2 = (x > 0); x[mask1] = 0.1; x[mask2] = 1`

Comment: Or if you want, like this: `mask1 = (x < 0); mask2 = (x > 0); np.putmask(x, mask1, 00.1); np.putmask(x, mask2, 1)`. You just have to create both masks before you apply either of them.