# Append a new column on a dataframe based on other dataframe with matching rows and fill the non-matching ones with value from the existing column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame look like 
df1

```
UserID group  day      sp  PU
213     test  12/11/14  3  311
314  control   13/11/14 4  345
354     test   13/08/14 5  376
```

and second data frame df2, it has information about the values in df1 column UserID, the matching rows in df2 and df1 are test-red and others should be itself.
df2

```
UserID
213
```

And what I am aiming is to append a new column `group2` to `df1` derived from the group column in df1 using matching values from `df2` as well as the values already there in `df1` as following,. For instance here UserId 213 is matching in df1 and df2 so it should be added in the newly appended column 'group2' as test-Red and otherwise it should as it is from `group` column. 
df1

```
 UserID group  day      sp  PU    group2
    213     test  12/11/14  3  311  test-Red
    314  control   13/11/14 4  345  control
    354     test   13/08/14 5  376  test-NonRed
```

This is what I tried,

```
def converters(df2,df1):
    if df1['UserId']==df2['UserId']:
           val="test-Red"
    elif df1['group']== "test":
         val="test-NonRed"      
    else:
          val="control"

    return val
```

But it throws error as following,

```
ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare
```

Comment: where is the `group2` come from ?

Comment: You definitely haven't provided enough information

Comment: group2 is the new column I needed to append to df1, that is my aiming result

Comment: group2 is derived from the group column in df1 as well as from the matching values in df2 column UserID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) :

```
df1['new'] = np.where(df1['UserID'].isin(df2['UserID']), 'test-Red', 
             np.where(df1['group'] == 'test','test-NonRed',df1['group']))
print (df1)
   UserID    group       day  sp   PU          new
0     213     test  12/11/14   3  311     test-Red
1     314  control  13/11/14   4  345      control
2     354     test  13/08/14   5  376  test-NonRed
```

Or [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df1['UserID'].isin(df2['UserID'])
m2 = df1['group'] == 'test'
df1['new'] = np.select([m1,m2], ['test-Red', 'test-NonRed'],default=df1['group'])
print (df1)
  UserID    group       day  sp   PU          new
0     213     test  12/11/14   3  311     test-Red
1     314  control  13/11/14   4  345      control
2     354     test  13/08/14   5  376  test-NonRed
```

More general solution:

```
print (df1)
   UserID     group       day  sp   PU
0     213      test  12/11/14   3  311
1     314   control  13/11/14   4  345
2     354      test  13/08/14   5  376
3    2131     test1  12/11/14   3  311
4     314  control1  13/11/14   4  345
5     354     test1  13/08/14   5  376

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'UserID':[213, 2131]})


m1 = df1['UserID'].isin(df2['UserID'])
m2 = df1['group'].isin(df1.loc[m1, 'group'])

df1['new'] = np.select([m1,m2],
                       [df1['group'] + '-Red', df1['group'] + '-NonRed'], 
                        default=df1['group'])
print (df1)
   UserID     group       day  sp   PU           new
0     213      test  12/11/14   3  311      test-Red
1     314   control  13/11/14   4  345       control
2     354      test  13/08/14   5  376   test-NonRed
3    2131     test1  12/11/14   3  311     test1-Red
4     314  control1  13/11/14   4  345      control1
5     354     test1  13/08/14   5  376  test1-NonRed
```

Comment: I like dual np.where. Very nice use of it sir. np. select too.

Comment: Yes, but select is better, if more conditions - more readable ;)

Comment: I havent used `.select` much.  Will use them in future more.

Comment: Sir used it now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888976/how-to-replace-all-elements-of-python-numpy-array-that-are-greater-than-a-severa/46889691#46889691 :)

Comment: Jezreal thanks for solution, but with control string its showing NonRed, I need control string as it is I dont anything to be appended to it

Comment: Do you think chain condition `df1['UserID'].isin(df2['UserID'])` to `(df1['UserID'].isin(df2['UserID'])) & (df1['group'] != 'control')` ?

Answer (score -1):

Can you use pd.merge and specify the how=outer parameter?  This would include all the data from both tables being joined

ie:

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='UserId')
```